# error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Partial<IConfig> | (() => Partial<IConfig>)'

Tags: ngx-mask

Installed and followed **Quickstart** instructions of [`ngx-mask`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask) for app.module.ts:

```
import { NgxMaskModule, IConfig } from 'ngx-mask'

export const options: Partial<IConfig> | (() => Partial<IConfig>) = null;

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
  ],
})
```

`ng serve` returns

> error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Partial
> | (() => Partial)'.

[image]

Angular v14, node 14.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
`Partial<IConfig>` --> `Partial<null|IConfig>`